# How to check if a cell is empty, return script. Google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This might be a very beginner question and might be answered many times here but I could not find it.

I created a button on google sheets that create a google doc filled with data obtained from google sheets.

I faced one problem when a row is not completed with data, the script will create google doc anyway.

I want the script to check if Cell ( for example, K2 ) is empty, it should not create a google doc.

I tried this but did not work:

if (row[11]==="") return;

thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There is an isBlank() function in class range which returns a boolena. So using the following statement `if(sh.getRange("A1").isBlank())` would return true or false.

Of course of you are working with 2D arrays from getValues() method then you can find nulls or blanks with `values[i][j] == null` or `values[i][j] == ''`

Comment: Thank you for replay
Unfortunately, It did not work 
this is script 
`function createNewGoogleDocs0() {
  const googleDocTemplate0 = DriveApp.getFileById('x');
  const destinationFolder0 = DriveApp.getFolderById('x');
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('x');
  const rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  rows.forEach(function(row, index){
  if (index === 0) return;
  if (row[23]) return;`

** Now it's checking row 2 if 23(X column) has data or not, if yes return. I want it to check if row 2 (A to K columns ) has data or not, If not return **